# Connect Github project with Gitlab

Tags: github, merge, gitlab, github-actions, gitlab-api

Is there a way to connect a GitLab project with Github? I mean when I push or make any modification to the Gitlab project it should be done automatically to another same copy in Github.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Some actions in [the marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=gitlab+) will allow you to trigger the Gitlab CI through Github Actions. Now, what you want to do would have to be implemented on Gitlab CI, triggering a workflow on Github Action (using for example a [workflow dispatch event](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch) through the Github API from the [Gitlab CI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/github.html)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is. Gitlab offers [Repository mirroring](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/repository_mirroring.html) out of the box for all tiers:

> Repository mirroring allows for the mirroring of repositories to and from external sources. You can use it to mirror branches, tags, and commits between repositories. It helps you use a repository outside of GitLab.
>
> A repository mirror at GitLab updates automatically. You can also manually trigger an update at most once every five minutes on GitLab.com with the limit set by the administrator on self-managed instances.
>
> There are two kinds of repository mirroring supported by GitLab:
>
> - Push: for mirroring a GitLab repository to another location.
> - Pull: for mirroring a repository from another location to GitLab.

I use this to synchronize my repos between Github and Gitlab and works fine for me

Comment: I tried to mirror my existing repository from Gitlab to Github (it is a project I was working on for a while).
I got an error:
13:close stream to gitaly-ruby: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Gitlab::Git::CommandError: remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com. remote: error: Trace:  remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information. remote: error: ..... is 162.60 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB To' .
I removed the large files, but why I still get this message?

Comment: I recommend to open another question for that